# Excel 2010 index match VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

Tried everything and can't seem to get this. Trying to replace values in Row B (SiteTag) of one worksheet with the proper sitetag from an index match in another worksheet.

> Worksheet(Site_Visit)
>   **SiteTag**
>   AL27
>   AS26
>   GBEM4
>   ...
>
> Worksheet(Sites)
>   **SiteTag**    **Project Name**
>   203AL27    AL27
>   203AS26    AS26
>   201GBEM4   GBEM4
>   ...        ...

I need to replace the values SiteTag in Sheets("Site_Visit") with the appropriate SiteTag from Sheets("Sites").

For now I've simply tried to get the code to place the correct index value into a variable in which I'll place as the value for each cell, and run it in a loop. But for the life of me can't get it to get a value. This is what I've tried for the variable (everything has been declared).

```
ST_Cells2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index("Sites!A2:A34", Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Site_Visit!B2", "Sites!B2:B34", 0), 0)
```

Where "Sites!A2:A34" is the range for the appropriate replacement value
"Sites_Visit!B2" is the lookup value
"Sites!B2:B34" is the lookup range

I'm getting a Run Time error `'1004' Unable to get the Match property of the WroksheetFunction class`. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Index and Match functions are expecting Ranges, but you are sending them strings. The easiest way to turn strings into Ranges is to use Excel's Range function:

```vba
st_cells2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Sites!A2:A34"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("Site_Visit!B2"), Range("Sites!B2:B34"), 0), 0)
```

Comment: Someboddy you are my hero. I've been working on this for two days and I swear I tried the Range function at some point. This totally made my day! Thanks.

Comment: hi i come up to this question too but i have multiple criteria. How can i achieve that?

Comment: @useR I haven't been using Excel for quite a while now(I now live in the Linux world and enjoy every moment), so I'm going to have to redirect you to Microsoft's article on the matter - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/59482

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but it run ok when I changed to "Application" indstead of WorksheetFunction:

`Cells(12, 12).Value = Application.Index("Sheet1!B1:9", 2)`

Somehow running the Function from Application directly worked...
/K